# Crafting parameterized SELECT query with array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

it's my first post here. I read a lot of similar topics, but I didn't find satisfying answer.

I can't craft a parameterized query with arrays.

My application has some kind of filter. Checkboxes represent country of recipe and list represent products that recipe contain. These parametrs are sending via AJAX by two arrays(country and list). I need craft a query, that select all records from table "recipes" where kraj_pochodzenia = params from array "country" and recipe contains ingredients = array "list".

Here's my code:

```
//query where we want filtering by ingredients list and country
if(isset($_POST['list']) && isset($_POST['country'])){ 
    $list = json_decode($_POST['list']);
    $list = array_map("htmlspecialchars", $list);
    $country = json_decode($_POST['country']);
    $country = array_map("htmlspecialchars", $country);

    //need statement here, for the rest ifs I will figure out :)

//query where we want filterin only by country
} else if (!isset($_POST['list']) && isset($_POST['country']) ) {
    $country = json_decode($_POST['country']);
    $country = array_map("htmlspecialchars", $country);

// query where we want only filtering by ingredients list 
} else if (isset($_POST['list']) && !isset($_POST['country'])) { 
    $list = json_decode($_POST['list']);
    $list = array_map("htmlspecialchars", $list);

} else {}
```

Here's my relation of database:

[image: relation of database]

There is many-to-many relation. Many recipes has many different ingredients. Nazwa_skladnika = name_ingredient

**@UPDATE**

 HTML CHECKBOXES, li are generating dynamic via AJAX (searching product in database, click in datalist, add to ul):

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <p class="lead">Wybierz kraj potrawy!</p>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="japanCheck" value="japonia" name="checky[]">
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="japanCheck">Japonia</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="thaiCheck" value="tajlandia" name="checky[]">
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="thaiCheck">Tajlandia</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="indiaCheck" value="indie" name="checky[]">
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="indiaCheck">Indie</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="chinaCheck" value="chiny" name="checky[]">
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="chinaheck">Chiny</label>
                </div>
                <p class="lead">Wprowadź produkt, który ma się zawierać w potrawie </p>
                  <input type="text" list="resultSearch" id="searchProduct" autocomplete="off" placeholder="np. papryka" name="products">
                  <span class="fa fa-search"></span>
                  <datalist id="resultSearch"></datalist>
                  <ul class="list-group" id="listProduct"></ul>
              </div>
          </div>
```

AJAX for sending array with checkboxes value and li values:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.form-check-input').on('change', function(){//za kazda zmiana filtra od kraju niech sie ajax odpala i przeszukuje dane
    var listOfProduct = $("#listProduct li").map(function(){ // trzeba sprawdzic czy lista jest juz zrobiona
                      return $(this).text();
    }).get();
    var checkBoxes =  $('.form-check-input:checked').map(function(){
      return this.value;
    }).get();

    if(listOfProduct !== undefined && listOfProduct.length > 0){ // jezeli lista produktow jest zrobiona odpalamy ajaxa z filtrem kraju i listy

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"filtering.php",
        dataType:"JSON",
        data: {
          country:JSON.stringify(checkBoxes),
          list:JSON.stringify(listOfProduct)
        },
        success: function(data){
          //trzeba zrobic by zdjecie dodawalo do karuseli na tym napis przepisu i tagi z opis_przepisu
        }
      })
    }else{//pusta lista sprawdzamy same potrawy na podstwie kraju
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"filtering.php",
        dataType:"JSON",
        data: {
          country:JSON.stringify(checkBoxes),
        },
        success: function(data){
          //trzeba zrobic by zdjecie dodawalo do karuseli na tym napis przepisu i tagi z opis_przepisu
        }
      })
    }
  });
   $('#listProduct').on('click',function(){ // teraz ajax na zmainie listy
     var listOfProduct = $("#listProduct li").map(function(){
                       return $(this).text();
     }).get();
     var checkBoxes =  $('.form-check-input:checked').map(function(){// sprawdzic czy jest filtr kraju wybrany
       return this.value;
     }).get();
     if(checkBoxes !== undefined && checkBoxes.length > 0){
       $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url:"filtering.php",
         dataType:"JSON",
         data: {
           country:JSON.stringify(checkBoxes),
           list:JSON.stringify(listOfProduct)
         },
         success: function(data){
           //trzeba zrobic by zdjecie dodawalo do karuseli na tym napis przepisu i tagi z opis_przepisu
         }
       })
     }else{ // sam filtr z produktami ze wszystkic krajow
       $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url:"filtering.php",
         dataType:"JSON",
         data: {
           list:JSON.stringify(listOfProduct)
         },
         success: function(data){
           //trzeba zrobic by zdjecie dodawalo do karuseli na tym napis przepisu i tagi z opis_przepisu
         }
       })
     }
   })
})
```

**@UPDATE2 - SOLUTION**

 Here's a code, PDO is the easiest way imo:

```
try{
          $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database;charset=utf8", $user, $password);

        }
      catch(PDOException $e){
          echo $e->getMessage();
        }


      if(isset($_POST['list']) && isset($_POST['country'])){ //query where we want filtering by ingre list and country
        $list = json_decode($_POST['list']);
        $list = array_map("htmlspecialchars", $list);
        $country = json_decode($_POST['country']);
        $country = array_map("htmlspecialchars", $country);
        $merge = array_merge($list,$country);
        $numberofparam = count($list);
        if(count($list)-1 >= 0 && count($country)-1 >= 0){
          $placeholders1 = str_repeat('?,', count($list) - 1)  . '?';
          $placeholders2 = str_repeat('?,', count($country) - 1) . '?';
          $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT
                                 r.nazwa_przepisu, r.opis_przepisu, r.zdjecie_przepisu, r.przygotowanie_przepisu, r.kraj_pochodzenia, r.spis_produktow
                                 FROM recipes r
                                 JOIN reci_ingre ri on r.id_przepisu = ri.id_przepisu
                                 JOIN ingredients i on ri.id_skladnika = i.id_skladnika
                                 WHERE i.nazwa_skladnika IN ($placeholders1) AND (kraj_pochodzenia IN ($placeholders2))
                                 GROUP BY r.id_przepisu
                                 HAVING COUNT(r.id_przepisu) = $numberofparam
                                 ORDER BY COUNT(r.id_przepisu) DESC");
          $stmt->execute($merge);
          $data = $stmt->fetchAll();
          echo json_encode($data);
        }


      }else if(!isset($_POST['list']) && isset($_POST['country']) ){//query where we want filterin only by country
        $country = json_decode($_POST['country']);
        $country = array_map("htmlspecialchars", $country);

        if(count($country)-1 >= 0){
          $placeholders = str_repeat('?,', count($country) - 1) . '?';
          $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT
                                 r.nazwa_przepisu, r.opis_przepisu, r.zdjecie_przepisu, r.przygotowanie_przepisu, r.kraj_pochodzenia, r.spis_produktow
                                 FROM recipes r
                                 WHERE kraj_pochodzenia IN ($placeholders)");
          $stmt->execute($country);
          $data = $stmt->fetchAll();
          echo json_encode($data);
      } exit();





      }else if(isset($_POST['list']) && !isset($_POST['country'])){ // query where we want only filtering by ingredients list
        $list = json_decode($_POST['list']);
        $list = array_map("htmlspecialchars", $list);
        $numberofparam = count($list);
        if(count($list)-1 >= 0){
          $placeholders = str_repeat('?,', count($list) - 1) . '?';
          $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT
                                 r.nazwa_przepisu, r.opis_przepisu, r.zdjecie_przepisu, r.przygotowanie_przepisu, r.kraj_pochodzenia, r.spis_produktow
                                 FROM recipes r
                                 JOIN reci_ingre ri on r.id_przepisu = ri.id_przepisu
                                 JOIN ingredients i on ri.id_skladnika = i.id_skladnika
                                 WHERE i.nazwa_skladnika IN ($placeholders)
                                 GROUP BY r.id_przepisu
                                 HAVING COUNT(r.id_przepisu) = $numberofparam
                                 ORDER BY COUNT(r.id_przepisu) DESC");
          $stmt->execute($list);
          $data = $stmt->fetchAll();
          echo json_encode($data);
        }

      exit();
    }
```

Comment: Can we see the HTML definition for $list and $country?

Comment: Done. The problem is, all data is correctly send to PHP file. I can't craft parameterized query with arrays. Can't bind them. In result of query i want get all records with recipes which contains a country from my checkbox array, and contains a ingredient from array product list (many-to-many relation in case of recipe-ingredient) :)

Comment: So your real question is “Can I pass arrays as parameters in a PDO query”?

Comment: My question is, how to craft a SELECT parameterized query with params from arrays. I don't mind using PDO or MYSQLI :)
Need to get all results from recipes, where kraj_pochodzenia = $country[0] or $country[1] etc  AND recipes contain ingredient like $list[0] $list[1] etc.. (its a pseudo code to explain what i mean) and parameterized this query.
Can't craft that kind of query cause it's use many-to-many relation :(

Comment: Actually, I think you can craft that query (because you’ve more or less done it with pseudo code). It may not be a simple query (and may take more than one), but I think you’ve already got a good start with the pseudo you’ve written. You just need to transfer your pseudo code to SQL.

Comment: Yup, I did it. Thanks for help and interesting in this topic.
There's a update with solution for others :)

Comment: Great. Post your answer below and accept it so others can use it as well :-)

Answer (score 1):

@UPDATE2 - SOLUTION
Here's a code, PDO is the easiest way imo:

```
try{
      $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database;charset=utf8", $user, $password);

    }
  catch(PDOException $e){
      echo $e->getMessage();
    }


  if(isset($_POST['list']) && isset($_POST['country'])){ //query where we want filtering by ingre list and country
    $list = json_decode($_POST['list']);
    $list = array_map("htmlspecialchars", $list);
    $country = json_decode($_POST['country']);
    $country = array_map("htmlspecialchars", $country);
    $merge = array_merge($list,$country);
    $numberofparam = count($list);
    if(count($list)-1 >= 0 && count($country)-1 >= 0){
      $placeholders1 = str_repeat('?,', count($list) - 1)  . '?';
      $placeholders2 = str_repeat('?,', count($country) - 1) . '?';
      $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT
                             r.nazwa_przepisu, r.opis_przepisu, r.zdjecie_przepisu, r.przygotowanie_przepisu, r.kraj_pochodzenia, r.spis_produktow
                             FROM recipes r
                             JOIN reci_ingre ri on r.id_przepisu = ri.id_przepisu
                             JOIN ingredients i on ri.id_skladnika = i.id_skladnika
                             WHERE i.nazwa_skladnika IN ($placeholders1) AND (kraj_pochodzenia IN ($placeholders2))
                             GROUP BY r.id_przepisu
                             HAVING COUNT(r.id_przepisu) = $numberofparam
                             ORDER BY COUNT(r.id_przepisu) DESC");
      $stmt->execute($merge);
      $data = $stmt->fetchAll();
      echo json_encode($data);
    }


  }else if(!isset($_POST['list']) && isset($_POST['country']) ){//query where we want filterin only by country
    $country = json_decode($_POST['country']);
    $country = array_map("htmlspecialchars", $country);

    if(count($country)-1 >= 0){
      $placeholders = str_repeat('?,', count($country) - 1) . '?';
      $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT
                             r.nazwa_przepisu, r.opis_przepisu, r.zdjecie_przepisu, r.przygotowanie_przepisu, r.kraj_pochodzenia, r.spis_produktow
                             FROM recipes r
                             WHERE kraj_pochodzenia IN ($placeholders)");
      $stmt->execute($country);
      $data = $stmt->fetchAll();
      echo json_encode($data);
  } exit();





  }else if(isset($_POST['list']) && !isset($_POST['country'])){ // query where we want only filtering by ingredients list
    $list = json_decode($_POST['list']);
    $list = array_map("htmlspecialchars", $list);
    $numberofparam = count($list);
    if(count($list)-1 >= 0){
      $placeholders = str_repeat('?,', count($list) - 1) . '?';
      $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT
                             r.nazwa_przepisu, r.opis_przepisu, r.zdjecie_przepisu, r.przygotowanie_przepisu, r.kraj_pochodzenia, r.spis_produktow
                             FROM recipes r
                             JOIN reci_ingre ri on r.id_przepisu = ri.id_przepisu
                             JOIN ingredients i on ri.id_skladnika = i.id_skladnika
                             WHERE i.nazwa_skladnika IN ($placeholders)
                             GROUP BY r.id_przepisu
                             HAVING COUNT(r.id_przepisu) = $numberofparam
                             ORDER BY COUNT(r.id_przepisu) DESC");
      $stmt->execute($list);
      $data = $stmt->fetchAll();
      echo json_encode($data);
    }

  exit();
}
```